# 'this' is undefined in express.js Router

Tags: typescript, express

And thanksf for taking the time to read this. I'm just starting out with express.js and typescript and came across an issue thats puzzling me. I'm trying to figure out why 'this' is undefined in the CompanyRouter functions.

The router is initialized like this:

```
this.express.use('/api/v1/company', new CompanyRouter(new CompanyService()).router);
```

Is it a contextual issue, or does express.js treat router functions as static functions?

```
import {Router, Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
import {Company} from '../models/Company';
import {ICompanyService} from '../interfaces/ICompanyService';

export class CompanyRouter {
    router: Router
    service: ICompanyService

    constructor(service : ICompanyService) {
        this.router = Router();
        this.service = service;
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        this.router.get('/', this.getAllCompanies);
        this.router.post('/', this.postCompany);
    }

    public async getAllCompanies(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const companies = this.service.findAll()
        res.send(companies);
    }

    public async postCompany(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const company = this.service.add(req.body);
        res.send(company);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the error, you are getting.

Comment: @RaghavGarg (node:12743) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'service' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is related how your methods are being called inside your `init()` function. Passing the reference of the function instead of calling it directly will make `this` undefined because it lost its reference.

So, I think the following code should work:

```
import {Router, Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
import {Company} from '../models/Company';
import {ICompanyService} from '../interfaces/ICompanyService';

export class CompanyRouter {
    router: Router
    service: ICompanyService

    constructor(service : ICompanyService) {
        this.router = Router();
        this.service = service;
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        this.router.get('/', (req, res, next) => this.getAllCompanies(req, res, next));
        this.router.post('/', (req, res, next) => this.postCompany(req, res, next));
    }

    public async getAllCompanies(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const companies = this.service.findAll()
        res.send(companies);
    }

    public async postCompany(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const company = this.service.add(req.body);
        res.send(company);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hey felipe, thanks for your solution. This did resolve the issue of 'this' no longer being defined. But the router doesn't appear to work with this implementation. I think this is due to my lack of understanding of the express router.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that it is wrong, you need to pass the correct parameters in the middlewares. Something like this:

    this.router.get('/', (req, res, next) => this.getAllCompanies(req, res, next));